# Compute a chain of functions in python

Tags: python, functional-programming

I want to get the result of a chain of computations from an initial value. I'm actually using the following code:

```
def function_composition(function_list, origin):
    destination = origin
    for func in function_list:
        destination = func(destination)
    return destination
```

With each function in `function_list` having a single argument.

I'd like to know if there is a similar function in python standard library or a better way (example: using lambdas) to do this.

Comment: This would be a fold of function application, in an FP style. E.g. in Haskell `foldr ($) 7 [(+1), (^3), (*2)]` evaluates to `2745`. `($)` is simply `\f x -> f x`. So `reduce` and `lambda` would be the python equivalent.

Comment: Your code is clear and concise - I would argue that there is no reason to try and compress it down.

Comment: @DonStewart: actually it's a fold of function composition.

Comment: @larsmans - depends on whether you want to fold composition and then apply, or just fold apply ... `foldr ($) x [(+1),(^2)]` vs `foldr (.) id [(+1),(^2)] $ x`.

Answer (score 20):

Fold while calling.

```
destination = reduce((lambda x, y: y(x)), function_list, origin)
```

Comment: Note that in 3.x, `reduce` is `functools.reduce()`.

Comment: I needed to reverse variables in the lambda: `destination = reduce((lambda x, y: y(x)), function_list, origin)`. Now it works.

Comment: Do you really believe this is a *better* way of doing this?

Comment: @larsmans I certainly find it easier to understand what this is doing and that it's correct.

Comment: It's a little more readable if you redefine the deprecated `apply` function: `apply = lambda func, value: func(value); destination = reduce(apply, function_list, origin)`.