# Chaining functions with multiple arguments

Tags: python, r, python-2.7, functional-programming, chain

Is there a way to chain functions with multiple arguments?

For the moment I *"chain"* my operation in `Python` like this:

```
def createDirIfNecessary(directoryName):
    if not os.path.exists(directoryName):
        print 'Creating directory [%s]'% directoryName
        os.makedirs(directoryName)
    return directoryName

cakeName = 'lemonPie'
cookDate = '2011-01-04'

#yewww very ugly, big blob of function call ...
myDir = os.path.join(getDbDir('kitchenCupboardDir'),'cakes', cakeName)
file  = os.path.join(createDirIfNecessary(myDir), cookDate + '.gz')
```

For example, in `R` there is a very elegant way to proceed using a 'pipe' `%>%` operator (pipe operator also present in `Haskell`). The equivalent code is:

```
cakeName = 'lemonPie'
cookDate = '2011-01-04'

file = getDbDir('kitchenCupboardDir') %>%
         file.path('cakes', cakeName) %>%
         createDirIfNecessary %>%
         file.path(paste0(cookDate,'.gz'))
```

Here there are only 4 functions, there can be 6, 7 wich can be easily chained. I can't use R unfortunately and I wonder if there is a solution in `python 2.7`

It is quite related to this topic but with further arguments:
[Better way to call a chain of functions in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20454118/better-way-to-call-a-chain-of-functions-in-python?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

The `fn` package [(see on GitHub](https://github.com/kachayev/fn.py) has the `>>` operator, and many other nice things for functional programming. You *can* do functional programming in python, even if ([see also this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017621/why-isnt-python-very-good-for-functional-programming)) it's not really the optimal way. Python can "chain" functions through methods:

```
file = getDbDir(...).makePath(...).createDir(...).getPath(...)
```

This is a way to chain operations.